# OPENSSL QUESTION - LINUX .cpp code

Tags: c++, openssl

in Ubuntu: I have a .cpp code with a string value. I would like to crypt it with aes and also use the base64 encoding. How to do that?! OpenSSL is a solution, but it crypts files or strings from the command line.:(

I would like to crypt and encode my string in my code. From the command line I just want to use `g++ test.cpp -o test -?` and a library that I need.

Answer (score 2):

For AES encryption check out http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt

To compile your app you will have to do :

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: Thx . Do you have an example of code written in c++ code? I would like to use both aes and base64 .

Comment: Here is the base64 example, http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/34/howto-base64-encode-with-cc-and-openssl/ You can use both codes in your C++ application.